# How can I read input node and output node from .h5 file in keras model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, object-detection

I trained my own dataset using MaskRCNN. My trained file is in .h5 file format. Now I want to know/read input node names and output node names.

How can I read?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you have the Keras .h5 file ready. Now, we need to load the model from that file using,

```
model = keras.models.load_model( 'model.h5' )
```

`model` represents the Keras model. Now, `model.input` will correspond to the input tensor.

```
input = model.input
output = model.output
```

Also, you get the output in a similar way. The `input` and `output` tensors will have their names. This can be observed by printing the tensor using Python's `print`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your answer is ok for my question, but. I saved only weight not model. However, now I understood my problem.